# How can I draw a continuously colored line in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'd like to add color to a single line plot depending on an array of values.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

xs=list(range(1000))
ys=[x**2 for x in xs]
cs=xs

fig=figure()
fig.line(xs, ys)
show(fig)
```

How can I add a continous color determined by a palette and the numeric values of `cs`? I've seen a `LinearColorMapper`, but I don't know how to apply it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Bokeh `1.0.4` varying the color along a single line is not supported. The HTML canvas that Bokeh renders to only supports lines with a single color, so accordingly, Bokeh only supports this as well. I'm not aware of any existing issue covering this, so certainly feel free to [make a feature request](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) if you are inclined.

Depending on exactly what you want to accomplish, it might be possible to use `multi_line` or `segments` to approximate this, by having many segments that each have a different color. However, results may not be perfect, as drawing individual segments means that nice line joins will not happen.

Alterntatively, [Bokeh is extensible](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html), so if you are aware of some third-party JS library that can draw these kinds of lines on an HTML canvas, you could hook that up to python code using a Bokeh extension.